# Hide/Show li elements for independent divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Trying to implement a hide/show results on a search page, what I have right now works, but not in the way I want. **As of now, the code is limiting all li's instead of 3 per div**

```
let searchResults       = document.querySelectorAll('div.test-class-3');
searchResults.forEach(function (searchResult) {
  console.log('result',searchResult)
  $(document).ready(function(){

    var list = $(".search-results li");
    var numToShow = 3;
    var button = $("#next");
    var numInList = list.length;
    list.hide();
    if (numInList > numToShow) {
      button.show();
    }
    list.slice(0, numToShow).show();

    button.click(function(){
        var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
        list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
        var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
        if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
          button.hide();
        }
    });

  });

})
```

[image]

My console.log returns two divs, these are unique, so basically forEach(searchResult) I want to only display 3 li's, each div should have the show more button. **As of now, the code is limiting all li's instead of 3 per div**

EDIT:

I've come up with a solution, though it's not DRY at all..How can I refactor this?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  var list = $(".search-results .reports");
  var numToShow = 3;
  var button = $(".next:eq(0)");
  var numInList = list.length;
  list.hide();
  if (numInList > numToShow) {
    button.show();
  }
  list.slice(0, numToShow).show();

  button.click(function(){
      var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
      list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
      var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
      if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
        button.hide();
      }
  });

});


$(document).ready(function(){

  var dashboardList = $(".search-results .dashboards");
  var dashboardNumToShow = 3;
  var dashboardButton = $(".next:eq(1)");
  var dashboardNumInList = dashboardList.length;
  dashboardList.hide();
  if (dashboardNumInList > dashboardNumToShow) {
    dashboardButton.show();
  }
  dashboardList.slice(0, dashboardNumToShow).show();

  dashboardButton.click(function(){
    console.log('event fired')
    console.log('arrayLength', dashboardNumInList)
      var dashboardShowing = dashboardList.filter(':visible').length;
      dashboardList.slice(dashboardShowing - 1, dashboardShowing + dashboardNumToShow).fadeIn();
      var dashboardNowShowing = dashboardList.filter(':visible').length;
      console.log('nowShowing', dashboardNowShowing)

      if (dashboardNowShowing >= dashboardNumInList) {
        dashboardButton.hide();
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the line:

```
var list = $(".search-results li");
```

Which is not limited within each search result.

What you'll need to do is limit that line to within the searchResult:

```
var list = $(".search-results li", searchResult);
```

Note that you may not also be selecting the correct button with the `#next` as well.

Comment: You're still not limiting to within a jQuery context (see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ )